# Swift 3 - Latest method for using API calls

Tags: ios, api, swift3

What is the latest and most current way to manage API calls in an iOS app using swift 3?

Is it NSURLSession? or is there another way to do it that is newer?

Comment: use Alamofire framework for api call

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3 NS prefix is removed, now following is the syntax for urlsession

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
         //do the work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3 - latest method call for api.

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)! //Pass the URL String format
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

_ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                        self.ProgressViewHide()
                        return
                    }
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
          let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                // Get Response on responseJSON
     }

}.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

So for new way in Swift 3.x you have to put like this.

Also, remember that your closure is work asynchronously, so I wrapped the call to be executed on main thread by using GCD.

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "Put your url")!)

     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                data, response, error in
                //print(error?.localizedDescription)

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject

                    //on main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.currentCode = json["code"]!! as! String

                    }

                }catch{
                    print("error\(error)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
```

But, I suggest you to use more easy way to handle networking using Alamofire,
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire